# Strange warning about container in SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene, skview

I have a curious warning on console:

> 2015-09-11 19:13:19.966 myApp[2171:693733] |error| Went all the way up
>   the container chain from  name:'myScene' frame:{{-160, -240},
>   {320, 480}}, but could not find any container that was one of the
>   ordered children of >.

There are no warning during compilation, app run just fines and this message appear from time to time.

### Update 1

Still here on Xcode 7 and Swift2